# How to access a scope variable in inline javascript inside a html page in thymeleaf and use it to change a css attribute

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

paperWidth is the angular scope variable. I want to set max-width of id="a" to paperWidth's value

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            ...
            document.getElementById('a').style.max-width = /*[[${paperWidth}]]*/ null;
            ...
        /*]]>*/
    </script>  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td th:text="${paperWidth}"></td>
            <td id="a">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td> 
       </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this script file within the head tags. Call this function "myFunction()" in "onload" attribute of the body tag. I would suggest to change the width of the table instead.

```
<script th:inline="javascript"> function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("a").style.width = [[${paperWidth}]]; } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-style` directive:

```html
<td id="a" ng-style="{'max-width':paperWidth}">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
```

Comment: the angular scope variable doesn't get the value this way

Comment: @JTJ What do you mean? how does the angular scope get the value then? is `paperWidth` not an angular scope variable? When why did you tag this with AngularJS and mentioned scope in title?

Comment: paperWidth is an angular scope variable. I meant to say that using the syntax that you've mentioned, max-width isnt being able to access the value of paperWidth.

Comment: @JTJ If it's a property of the scope agaist which the HTML is compiled, it will be available. Otherwise you should show the code so that we can see why it's not available...